# CLI script to make Google API queries - how to authenticate

Tags: google-photos-api

I want to write a script that will pull down Google photos and put them somewhere else.

I do not want to require the user to setup a google project and create api keys for the project. Is there a way with Google to open a browser and generate a code that the user can put into the script to get credentials?

I understand Oauth in a browser, how can I do it from a script?